# Using Java reflection, can I access a private field of type private static nested class?

Tags: java, reflection

I've looked through every entry related to Java reflection I can find and none seem to address the situation I'm dealing with. I have a class A with a static nested class in it, B. Class A also has as one of its fields, an array of type B, called bArray. I need to access this field from outside the class as well as the private members of the elements of bArray. I have been able to get the static nested class using getDeclaredClasses and I would normally get the private field bArray with getDeclaredFields and setAccessible but I can't seem to put it all together to be able to iterate through bArray from outside the class.

Here is an example class structure that I'm working with.

```
public class A {
    private A.B[] bArray = new A.B[16];

    private static class B {
        private int theX;
        private int theY;

        B(int x, int y) {
            this.theX = x;
            this.theY = y;
        }
        // More methods of A.B not included   
    }
}
```

I ultimately need to get at bArray and its fields theX and theY from outside of class A.